Excel Chart: invert data label font color
How do you invert the color of a chart data label?
The following code is based on this one by Tim Williams and changes the label font color based on the label value:
Sub FlipLabelFontColor()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim j As Long
    With ActiveChart
        For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel
                    .Font.color = IIf(Val(.Text) < 0, vbRed, vbGreen)
                End With
            Next j
        Next k
    End With
End Sub

How do you change the color based on another color?
I'd like to invert white to black:
Sub InvertLabelFontColor()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim j As Long
    With ActiveChart
        For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel
'                    If .Font.color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
'                        .Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
'                    End If
                End With
            Next j
        Next k
    End With
End Sub


And what's wrong with your last piece of code? The one after "I'd like to invert white to black:"... Do you want it to also revers black with white? Should other color pairs be involved?

Initially, it wouldn't change the color. In my actual workbook, it didn't do. Tried restarting Excel, nothing happened. Even restarted the machine, nothing. I was 'making sure' it wasn't working, before posting the question. After your comment, I tested it again. In an empty workbook. And it does work.

Only noticed a little difference. Let's say, your labels' category is bold and your value is not bold. The first code using .Font.color turns that value line into bold.
The second code using .Format.TextFrame2... does not change the font style.

No, no other colors involved. I was only looking for a way to invert white. For the few cases where the font color in the cell is white on a dark background but should be black in the chart.

Sub InvertLabelFontColor_v2()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim j As Long
    With ActiveChart
        For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j).DataLabel
                    With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
                        If .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        End If
                    End With
                End With
            Next j
        Next k
    End With
End Sub

